# Return $_POST works of safari but not on Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, php, forms, input

I have and form I am submitting in Chrome and Safari this works fine however in Firefox and IE it does not find the submitted value

**the form:**

```
<form action="myform.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <input id="my-item-calc" name="my-item-calc" value="29.00">
         <input type="submit"></form>
```

**config.php**

```
$config['checkoutPath']           = 'myform.php';
$config['calc']['calcdel']        = 'my-item-calc';
$config['item']['id']        = 'my-item-id';    // Item finance
```

my form.php

```
public function display_cart() {

        $config = $this->config; 

        $id    = $config['item']['id'];
        $calcdel = $config['calc']['calcdel'];


        // Use config values as literal indices for incoming POST values
        // Values are the HTML name attributes set in config.json
        $id    = $_POST[$id];
        $calcdel= $_POST[$calcdel];
}
```

The error message I'm getting in
Firefox and IE

```
Undefined index: calc 
Undefined index: my-item-id
```

While Safari and Chrome display

```
 Undefined index: my-item-calc
Undefined index: my-item-id
```

(this is fine as it works)

Any idea why it works in safari/chrome and not in Firefox, and how can I fix this any help welcome

Comment: I suggest using your browser tools to see what the problem browsers are actually submitting to the server in the POST request. If I had to guess, I'd say maybe using hyphens in parameter names is potentially an issue. Stick to alphanumeric characters if you can, or replace the hypens with underscores maybe. I don't know for sure, can't test it right now, but it strikes me as a potential issue. However the best thing to do is actually examine the request body and see whether it contains what you're expecting. You can also `var_dump($_POST);` on the PHP side to see what's coming in. Debug it!!

Comment: just for the record, what `var_dump($config)` would say in your function, right after `$config = $this->config;`?

Comment: how is `$config['calc']` defined?

Comment: @Mouser I am not sure I don't understand even very much how $config['item']  is defined, can you point me in the direction where to look for this so I can add ['calc'] to it I presume you are thinking in .js files cause I can't find it in the php files. Thanks for looking

Comment: Not without more code. We need to know the class that defines `$this->config`

Comment: @Mouser I'm so sorry I can find only the following, $config = $jcart->config; and in class Cart public $config = array();